# woocommerce apply function on a specific category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to seek for help about my issue on woocommerce.

I have implemented the minimum order increment snippet from woocommerce. 
now what I am trying to do is I want to only make this code work on specific product categories.

this is the working code from woocommerce that I am trying to customize:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );


function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    if ( is_singular( 'product' )) {

        $args['input_value']    = 10;   // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }

    $args['max_value']  = 1000;     // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 10;       // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 10;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

// Variations
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );


function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 1000;        // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 10;      // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

I already tried to customize it and add "is_product_category" in  the code but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can get product categories form `$product->category_ids`

check bellow code. Hope this will helpful for you.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){

  if(in_array( '35',$product->category_ids))
  {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' )) {

        $args['input_value']    = 10;   // Starting value (we only want to affect product pages, not cart)
    }

    $args['max_value']  = 1000;     // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 10;       // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 10;    // Quantity steps

   } 
      return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur! I tested the code you gave, the minimum value is working but can still be reduced and the quantity steps is not working as well. And if you can help me with adding multiple product ids. Thank you very much!